# What gem\plugin do you advice to use in order to make HTTP requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-3, request

I am using Ruby on Rails and I would like to make HTTP requests in a more "confortable" and "smart" way of using the Ruby `net/http` [standard library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html).

So, **what do you advice to use in order to make HTTP requests?** I heard there are some gems that make multiple requests in parallel, but I am not sure to do the right choice.

P.S.: I need some of reliable because I am trying to implement a messaging system between multiple applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like **[curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/) and [typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus)** depending on the situation. I'd use Curb for really simple things, and typhoeus for more complex requests.

I would advise against libs [curb-fu](https://github.com/gdi/curb-fu) or [patron](http://www.rubyinside.com/patron-a-simpler-ruby-http-client-2067.html) that are not stable enough when you try to do things a bit too complicated (tried both a few months ago, it might have changed since).

You also have [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) that can do the trick for you, but personnally I'm not a big fan of the way it works (but that's just me).